# TypeError: Cannot read property 'stateUpdate' (Which is a function) of undefined / Passing data from Parent to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having an issue of passing a function from parent to child component in `react js`.

I have tried to pass the vale to the component as props but it is showing the `type error` as defined in the question. i am not able to figure out why is it happening.

Is it because of mapping, if so how to solve it because mapping is important.

Parent Component:

```
stateUpdate(){
      alert("hi");
    }
    render() {

          const tabList =  this.state.productMapData.map(function(object, i){
            return <TableList obj={object} ids = {productRegistrationArrId} key={i}
```

Error here:

```
 parent= {this.stateUpdate.bind(this)}></TableList>
              })
        return (
          <div> 
            <div style={{ marginTop: 10, marginLeft: "10%" }}>
            <Link to="/api/productregistration" className="btn btn-info" onClick = {this.onDeleteDb} >
                Back to List
            </Link>
```

Child Component:

```
onUpdate(){
        this.props.parent;    
    }
```

Comment: can you please post the complete components and errors ?

Answer (score 0):

In parent stateUpdate function declare using arrow function then you may not get this issue. I have mentioned sample code below please find it

```
stateUpdate =()=> {
  alert("hi");
}
```

and in child component in update function you have to call parent function like

```
onUpdate=()=>{
        this.props.parent();  
       // here you have to change parent to parent()
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your solution but its not working. Is it not working because of mapping.

Comment: can you try once removing bind from  this function parent= {this.stateUpdate.bind(this)}></TableList> and only pass the function is like parent= {this.stateUpdate}></TableList> because you are passing function not values right. you can use this changes along above solution

Comment: @RaghavBist It is better to post complete code then we can able to understand exactly where was problem.